# Chi-squared test with Yates' correction in Excel

Tags: excel, probability, chi-squared

How can one calculate the corresponding p-value for Chi-squared with Yates' continuity correction using Excel? Without the correction, it is simple to use the `CHISQ.TEST` function. There is nothing on correction in the [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/chisq-test-function-2e8a7861-b14a-4985-aa93-fb88de3f260f). Minimal working example to follow.

My contingency table (B2:C3) would look like this:

|  | No | Yes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Men** | 1659 | 92 |
| **Women** | 323948 | 11090 |

And my expected frequencies (B5:C6) are:

|  | No | Yes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Men** | 1693 | 58 |
| **Women** | 323914 | 11124 |

In order to calculate the p-value we can use

```
CHISQ.TEST(B2:C3, B5:C6)
```

How to apply correction in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to achieve that.

**Step 1.** Calculate the Chi-square with Yates' correction using the following formula: `=(ABS(B2-B5)-0.5)^2/B5` and the same for the other three fields.

|  | No | Yes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Men** | 0.66 | 19.15 |
| **Women** | 0.00 | 0.10 |

Chi-squared value is the sum of all four values.

**Step 2.** The p-value can be calculated using:

`=CHISQ.DIST.RT(<Chi-squared value>,<degrees of freedom>)`.